# How to optimize query with Inline Function in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a table TAB_1 with following Schema

```
    CAR_NO(Varchar)  START_DATE(Date)  ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME(Number)  SOURCE_POINT(Varchar) 
   END_POINT(Varchar)
```

Table TAB_2 with following Schema

```
CAR_NO(Varchar)   ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL(Date)  EVENT_CODE(Varchar)
```

My query is :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT CAR_NO,START_DATE FROM TAB_1 WHERE
(TRUNC(START_DATE +CASE WHEN ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME=0 THEN NULL ELSE ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME END/1440)='10-Feb-2020' )  
    AND SOURCE_POINT=END_POINT
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT  CAR_NO,START_DATE FROM TAB_2 WHERE EVENT_CODE='TD' 
    AND TRUNC( ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL)='10-Feb-2020'
```

Column **ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME** stores the time value in minutes,Column **ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL** stores the date as timestamp value , I am trying to find all the cars which terminate on 10-Feb-2020 .Data can be absent from any of the tables so I have used UNION Operation here ,on top of this query I have to apply more operations ,so overall it is taking time of 35 seconds aprox. Please guide to optimize this query .

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `trunc()` on the column value will prevent an index on that column being used (unless it's a function-based index). It's better to use a date range, covering the entire day you're interested in. Adding the time offset to the `start_date` will also impact the index; and `'10-Feb-2020'` is a string not a date, so you're forcing implicit conversion - never a good idea. You also don't need `distinct` with `union` as (unlike `union all`) that eliminates duplicates anyway.

I'd suggest something like this as a starting point:

```
select car_no, start_date
from tab_1
where source_point = end_point
and start_date >= date '2020-02-10' - actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute
and start_date < date '2020-02-11' - actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute
union
select car_no, start_date
from tab_2
where event_code='TD' 
and actl_time_of_arrvl >= date '2020-02-10'
and actl_time_of_arrvl < date '2020-02-11'
```

The `actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute` gives you same effect as `ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME END/1440`; the first is an interval data type, the second is a fraction of a day, but both represent the number of minutes as a value that can be added to a date value.

I'm using date literals, which are still hard-coded. If you're really using a parameter you can add `interval '1' day` to the date you want instead of hard-coding one day later. Either way that will look for values at or after midnight on the first date, and *before* midnight on the second date - which covers all possible times that day.

The first branch still can't really use the index properly because of the variability of referring to another column value in the range calculation, but if you know for example that `actual_arrival_time` is within 24 hours you could help it with that more rigid restriction:

```
select car_no,start_date
from tab_1
where source_point = end_point
and start_date >= date '2020-02-10'
and start_date < date '2020-02-10' + interval '2' day -- depending on allowed ranges
and start_date + actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute >= date '2020-02-10'
and start_date + actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute < date '2020-02-10' + interval '1' day 
union
select car_no, start_date
from tab_2
where event_code='TD' 
and actl_time_of_arrvl >= date '2020-02-10'
and actl_time_of_arrvl < date '2020-02-10' + interval '1' day
```

Here `start_date >= date '2020-02-10'` gives the index a lower bound to search for (assuming `actual_arrival_time` can't be negative, which seems reasonable); and `start_date < date '2020-02-10' + interval '2' day` gives an upper bound. What that upper bound is will depend on the allowed values, particularly for `actual_arrival_time`.

It's unclear in your question whether `tab1.start_date` is always midnight, so you might be able to simplify the first part of the check to an exact date match instead of a range. But then looking at `actual_arrival_time` probably wouldn't be necessary... if `start_date` is actually always midnight and `actual_arrival_time` is constrained to between 0 and 1440 then it could be as simple as:

```
select car_no,start_date
from tab_1
where source_point = end_point
and start_date >= date '2020-02-10'
and start_date < date '2020-02-10' + interval '1' day
union
...
```

just like the second branch. But the way you've tried to approach it suggests that might not be the case, and you just need to narrow the initial index search as much as possible before then filtering on the exact time. I suspect the `actual_arrival_time` could represent several days, or even weeks or months; so going back to the previous version, the

```
and start_date < date '2020-02-10' + interval '2' day -- depending on allowed ranges
```

would extend to the maximum you'd expect to see; or could probably be omitted completely.

You need to look at the execution plan to see what it is actually doing though, probably for the overall query and each branch of the union separately.

If you're going to be doing this a lot it might be worth adding the calculated value `start_date + actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute` to `tab1` as a virtual column, and indexing that.

Comment: Can you please explain                                                                                                               1)   start_date >= date '2020-02-10' - interval '1' day  ,here we require date 10Feb , but subtracting from interval '1' day ,would result in 9 Feb                                                                                                        2)  start_date + actual_arrival_time * interval '1' minute  , why are we multiplying actual_arrival_time*interval '1' minute

Comment: @radha - I'm not sure (1) was quite right, assuming `actual_arrival_time` can't be negative, so I've adjusted and added further explanation; and added a note about (2).

Answer (score 1):

Strange way to deal with date and time i guess.
First of all examine your execution plan.

I suppose with few data it works like a charm but with lots of data, performance is gone.

Starting with the UNION, it is a performance issue itself.

Inline Operations like you are doing in TAB_1 dismisses usage of indexes. I hope you have indexes in ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME and ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME fields, but in your case they are not being used.
I suppose this query is in the middle of a process, so you colud come with a little workaround done before executing it

1.Know your starting minute for your period: e.g. param 'startMinute'.

2.Know your ending minute for your period: e.g. param 'endMinute'.

3.Rewite query

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAR_NO,START_DATE 
  FROM TAB_1 
 WHERE START_DATE >=  startMinute
   AND START_DATE <   endMinute
   AND SOURCE_POINT = END_POINT
UNION
.
.
.
```

I also hope you have an index in TAB_2.ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL, but also with the use of trunc, does not use index.
Maybe you need to create a **function based index** *TRUNC(ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL)* Index.
I'm sure you will find the following link very interesting:

https://blog.dbi-services.com/index-on-truncdate-do-you-still-need-old-index/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting by rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT CAR_NO, START_DATE
FROM TAB_1
WHERE SOURCE_POINT = END_POINT AND
      TRUNC(START_DATE + ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) = DATE '2020-02-10'
UNION -- ON PURPOSE TO REMOVE DUPLICATES
SELECT CAR_NO, START_DATE
FROM TAB_2
WHERE EVENT_CODE = 'TD' AND
      TRUNC(ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL) = DATE '2020-02-10' ;
```

Then for this query, you can define the following function-based indexes:

```
create index idx_tab_1_f1 on tab_1 (TRUNC(START_DATE + ACTUAL_ARRIVAL_TIME * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE), SOURCE_POINT, END_POINT);

create index idx_tab_2_f2 on tab_2 (EVENT_CODE, TRUNC(ACTL_TIME_OF_ARRVL));
```

You can also rephrase the query if you want to include the time component of the date in the index.  It is unclear whether that would be useful for other queries.